# subprocess.popen not working in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt

I've a small function in which it creates a report file from the contents of a GUI widget. Now i'm using subprocess.Popen to open the report file using kwrite but it does'nt work.
Am i missing something here. please help this is the code which i wrote:

```
.....    
def createreport(self):
            text = self.textEdit_2.toPlainText()
            copytext= (str('%s') %text)
            name=Ui_Dialog.fileName
            print Ui_Dialog.fileName
            Ui_Dialog.fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,'save result file', '/home/harisyam/Desktop/transfer')
            file=open(Ui_Dialog.fileName,'w')
            file.write(copytext)
            file.close()
            subprocess.Popen('kwrite '+Ui_Dialog.fileName ,shell=True)
```

the same code when i use it in python shell it works what is the problem here?

Error which i get when i run it in my gui code:  a: k: command not found

Comment: a: k: command not found this is the error i get

Comment: Have your check `Ui_Dialog.fileName` is python string ? (Not QtCore.QString). Id not , can use `str(Ui_Dialog.fileName)` ?

Comment: it worked yeah it should be type converted thank you very much, I used tkinter before the above function worked because it is returning a  python string. Anyways thank you @KitsuneMeyoko

Comment: You’re welcome. Then, I move it to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not python string, It's `QtCore.QString`, To fix it, try convert it to python string;

```
subprocess.Popen('kwrite '+ str(Ui_Dialog.fileName), shell=True)
```